# simple html dom grabbing h1 header

Tags: php, html, dom, simple-html-dom

I just learning about simple_html_dom.php,
I try to get the h1 content with some class.

```
<h1 class="entry-title">example for the header</h1>
```

here the raw html file from the website that i want to get the content.

```
    <header class="entry-header">
    <div class="entry-meta">
        <span class="cat-links"><a href="https://xxxxx/2016/08/11/xxxxxxx" rel="category tag">News</a></span>
    </div>
    <h1 class="entry-title">example for the header</h1>
    <div class="entry-meta">
        <span class="entry-date"><a href="https://xxxxx/2016/08/11/xxxxxxx" rel="bookmark"><time class="entry-date" datetime="2016-08-11T11:54:07+00:00">11 August 2016</time></a></span> 
        <span class="byline"><span class="author vcard"><a class="url fn n" href="https://xxxxx/2016/08/11/xxxxxxx" rel="author">wndwnrt</a></span></span>          
        <span class="comments-link"><a href="https://xxxxx/2016/08/11/xxxxxxx">1 Comment</a></span>
    </div>
</header>
```

here my code to get the h1 class="entry-title" content (example for the header)

```
<?php
 require_once __DIR__.'/simple_html_dom.php';
 $html = new simple_html_dom();
 $html->load_file('https://xxxxx/2016/08/11/xxxxxxx');
 $header_1 = $html->find('h1[class="entry-title"]')->innertext;
?>
<table border="1">
 <thead>
   <tr>
     <th><?php echo $header_1; ?></th>
  </tr>
 </thead>
</table>
```

when i run the code, the result is error:

```
Trying to get property of non-object
```

can anyone tell where is the error? and what i should to do?
Thank you very much.

Comment: var_dump($header_1) and see what is coming in this

Comment: @aman, it show "NULL" as the result. thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes you see that error because you are passing only one argument to the find function.

```
$header_1 = $html->find('h1[class="entry-title"]')->innertext
```

now try this:

```
$header_1 = $html->find('h1[class="entry-title"]',0)->innertext
```

because you also have to pass the number of the h1 you are trying to get!

Comment: As shown in [the documentation](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm#frag_find_basic).